# How to get previous year's date relative to week of year

Tags: php, datetime

How can I get the same day of the same [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) week number but in the previous year using php?

I am familiar with extracting this soft of information from a time stamp. Is there a built-in way for me to go from day of week, week of year and year to time stamp?

Comment: do you mean, if today is `2012-11-12 10:00:00 Monday Week 45` you want to get `2011-11-07 10:00:00 Monday week 45`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the combination of both `date` and `strtotime` like so:

```
// get the timestamp
$ts = strtotime('today');

// get year, week number and day of week
list($year, $week, $dow) = explode('-', date('Y-W-N', $ts));

// use the "YYYY-WXX-ZZ" format    
$format = ($year - 1) . "-W$week-$dow";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($format)), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$now = time(); // Mon, 12 Nov 2012
$targetYear = date('Y', $now) - 1; // 2011
$targetWeek = date('\\WW-N', $now); // W46-1
$lastYear = strtotime($targetYear . $targetWeek); // Mon, 14 Nov 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$date = "2012-11-13";
echo getLastYearWeek($date);
function getLastYearWeek($date)
{
    $last_year = date("Y-m-d W N", strtotime("-52 Weeks ".$date));

    return $last_year;
}
```

Or just,

```
$last_year = date("Y-m-d W N", strtotime("-52 Weeks ".$date));
```

Use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for mktime. have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Unfortunately, mktime does not have a day-of-week or week-of-year argument. Otherwise it _would_ be exactly what I need.